# fetch data from website while using log in data

Tags: php, flutter, dart, http, fetch

So I am trying to fetch data from a website (https://www.porsche-914.com/forum), specifically the different under-forums. (You can look up what I mean whitout logging in if you go to SECTOR live! -> SECTOR live! News, that's the list I want to get (https://www.porsche-914.com/forum/board.php?board=9)) Thats no problem as the Website is available publicly...On this page...

[image: On this public website it's working]

Further I want to use a username and a password stored before via sharedPreferences (don't worry, will be encrypted before final app release) on the http request to request as a logged in user, as you can't see everything on the site if not logged in (for example try going to AKTUELL -> NEUIGKEITEN (https://www.porsche-914.com/forum/board.php?board=4) and you'll see just the login-page).

[image: Not here, this part of the website is private and therefor my code doesn't show the contents but the login page]

How would something like that be possible?

Here is my code for fetching, public sites work, private are still private... (neumorphism Post is a Card showing text, it's just a style option, and yes, i'm using cardColor for the text color xD) ()

```
excutePosts() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    var url = Uri.parse(https://www.porsche-914.com/forum/board.php?board=4);

    var accName = prefs.getString('accName');
    var accPass = prefs.getString('accPass');

    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map['name'] = accName;
    map['passwd'] = accPass;

    var login = await http.post(
      url,
      body: map,
    );
    var response = await http.get(url);
    posts = [];
    BeautifulSoup bs = BeautifulSoup(response.body);
    final tBody = bs.findAll('tbody')[6];
    final allThemen = tBody.findAll('tr');
    allThemen.forEach((element) {
      posts.add(
        NeumorphismPost(
          text: element.text,
          title: element.text,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
          textColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
          titleColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
          onTap: () {},
        ),
      );
    });
    return posts;
  }
```